# UIImage smart resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have problem with making resizable UIImage where corners are not resized. What I want to achieve is to resize middle part using UIImageResizingModeTile. I.e. it should look something like following figure where corners A, B, C, D are original and all other parts are resized:

```
|-------------|
|A|         |B|
|-------------|
|             |
|             |
|-------------|
|C|         |D|
|-------------|
```

I tried with resizableImageWithCapInsets: but it doesn't resize middle parts well in way they are not made as pattern, but instead then are stretched which looks pretty bad. I noticed that because my image has "bubble" border so it's pretty noticeable. Take a look at sample image, it may be helpful.
[image]

Comment: Did you try `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` in order to specify a resizing mode? That said, it appears as though the default resizing mode is to tile anyway so that might not explain it.

Comment: I tried but it's not tiled and it looks quite bad. I think this can't be done this way because UIImage just doesn't offer methods for something like that..

Comment: Can you post some actual sample code? What you're describing is exactly what `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` is for. It should be working fine if you're using it correctly.

Comment: I used following code in drawRect:
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudbubble_1"];
    image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4)];
    [image drawInRect:rect];
I resized image to 40x21px and on small sizes it looks pretty good, but when UITableViewCell grows it looks pretty blurry and bubble loose their original shape, like they are not tiled bit stretched instead.